# custom Auto increment in Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have three customer Id in my table, Let's Say A,B,C.I want to create order table for managing orders from these customers. I want to create orderID columns in such away that it must be auto increment with cunstomer Id appended eg. orderID column records :

```
A_1  --->A's 1st order,
A_2  --->A's 2nd order,
B_1  --->B's 1st order,
C_1  --->C's 1st order,
A_3  --->A's 3rd order,
C_2  --->C's 2nd order,
C_3  --->C's 3rd order,
B_2  --->B's 2nd order,
A_4  --->A's 4th order,
A_5  --->A's 5th order
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `order_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_customer_orders` (`customer_id` ASC)
);
```

This allows you to easily `INSERT` your orders without ever thinking about the generated identifier. The additional `created` row will allow you to sort them and give them the number's you'd like.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `customer_id` = 1 ORDER BY `created`");

$orders = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $orders[] = $row;
}

echo count($orders) , PHP_EOL; // 42

foreach ($orders as $delta => $order) {
    echo "Your order #" , ($delta + 1) , " with the unique identifier {$order["order_id"]}." , PHP_EOL;
}
```

Just an example.

Comment: I want order_id should be serial for respective client. If I query the orders tables for particular customer then it must show the serial order nos.....